# ownCloud Setup: SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for user 'owncloud'@localhost' (using password:YES)

Tags: mysql, owncloud

I wanted to setup my owncloud installation on my raspberry pi 2. So, I created an mysql database and user.

```
CREATE DATABASE owncloud;

CREATE USER 'owncloud'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON owncloud. * TO 'owncloud'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After I type all nessesairy parameters into the webinterface of the  owncloud-setup, I recevied:

> Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect the database: An exeption occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000][1045] Access denied for user 'owncloud'@'localhost' (using password:YES)

Sadly, my resent sreach on similar topics didn't result in any functional hint on this problem. So, I would be happy about further suggestions.

Comment: Did you check if you can log into mysql with this user `owncloud` and the password you expect it to have?

Comment: Sure, I did this using "mysql -u owncloud -p" and then "use owncloud;". It worked fine without errors.

Comment: I'm thinking if you didn't make a typo because in error message there's `'owncloud'@localhost'` - missing `'` before `localhost` or redundand after `owncloud`. I'm not should how it should look like.

Comment: No, It is a typing mistake.

Comment: I had the same problem. After I replaced "localhost" for "127.0.0.1" in owncloud's setup form for MySQL it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work.

Comment: @Askaga Oh my ... 127.0.0.1 did the trick on my setup ! Thx

Comment: Thanx 127.0.0.1 worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Look at this: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/installation/installation_wizard.html#database-choice
2. In Terminal: mysql_upgrade --force -u root -p
3. Use administrative MySQL »root«-user and password with the Installation Wizard
4. Check that the Database not exist which you create with the Installation Wizard
5. If nothing helps, start with sqlite, then migrate to mysql like this: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_database/db_conversion.html

Comment: 5. was the solution. The date base was created as written above.

Answer (score 2):

Just replace `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` in Owncloud's setup form for MySQL as mentioned in comments above by Askaga

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, **explicitly** re-access the database from the terminal solves the problem for me. Just give mysql an empty line with

```
mysql -u root -e ";"
```

This should be an individual command **after** you created database and database user.

Sure, you should always check whether

1. There are users with an empty username. Remove them.
2. Remove "test" database.
3. Grant appropriate permission to your database user.
4. Last but not least `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Search other posts for instructions. I'm just providing a possible solution if you come across a situation where none of the above works.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270733/automate-mysql-secure-installation-with-echo-command-via-a-shell-script)'s a good example to properly setup mysql after installation. FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Mask the DB password in the installation screen (the **password should not be visible**, only dots) and retry.

Comment: May be put this as comment.

Comment: @αƞjiβ putting a comment is not possible as a novice user (<50 reputations)

Answer (score 0):

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1, Owncloud 10.
```

Check the contents of `config.php` in my case located at `/var/www/owncloud/config/`.
Specialy items `dbuser` and `dbpasswrd`. 
Read `config.sample.php` in the same directory for info.