# Installing mysql and creating a database on AL2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, ec2-userdata

I have a user data script that I am trying to use to install mysql and create a database on an AL2 instance using terraform. The installation looks great as I could verify using `systemctl status mysql`, however the creation of the database keeps throwing `mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure. ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`  error when i inspected cloud-init logs. any ideas why this keeps happening and how i could resolve it?
this is the user data script i am running

```
    user_data = <<-EOF
            #!/bin/bash
            #install mysql
            sudo rpm --import https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql-2022
            wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
            sudo yum localinstall -y mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
            sudo yum install -y mysql-community-server 

            #start & enable database
            sudo systemctl start mysqld
            sudo systemctl enable mysqld

            sudo mysql_secure_installation <<SCRIPT

                  y
                  Password123!
                  Password123!
                  y
                  y
                  y
                  y
                  SCRIPT
                  #create lyncdb database
                  sudo mysql -u root -pPassword123! -e "CREATE DATABASE lyncdb;"
                  sudo mysql -u root -pPassword123! -e "CREATE USER 'lyncdbuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'lyncPassw3rd!';"
                  sudo mysql -u root -pPassword123! -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON lyncdb.* TO 'lyncdbuser'@'localhost';"           
            EOF
```

[mysqld running status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ecpg.png)
[cloud init logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMTST.png)

Comment: Mysql typically doesn't have a default password when installed this way you are providing two different passwords for the same user.

Comment: yeah I just realised this, I corrected the password and i think it's still the same problem

Comment: There shouldn't be a password for the root user until you set one.

Comment: I set the password for the root user with the script below, correct me if i'm doing something wrong 
sudo mysql_secure_installation <<SCRIPT
                  y
                  Password123!
                  Password123!
                  y
                  y
                  y
                  y
                  SCRIPT

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36916378/5389997 answer to the duplucate question - you are missing an extra enter to indicate blank password.

Comment: i placed the extra enter and still did not work, could it be an al2 problem?