# Mariadb 10.5.x and issues with Wordpress thanks to "mysql.user" being a view now

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I just discovered the silly new issue of MariaDB's latest version having `mysql.user` as a view. All my imported Wordpress databases suddenly cannot connect from the blogs. When I try to even list mysql.user it shows me this:

```
> select * from mysql.user; 
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s)
or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack 
rights to use them
```

What can we do to solve this?

Edit: Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o), but it does not have a solution, only a suggestion. The `ALTER USER` command -- where to use and with what settings? Do I have to somehow alter the rights for every Blog database?

Comment: `USE mysql;  SHOW CREATE VIEW user;`

Comment: The other question was a bit different. `SELECT current_user()` to see what user you are running. Hopefully you haven't changed the `mariadb.sys` user that gives the required privileges for the view. Maybe try running `mariadb-upgrade`. Did you upgrade from an older version? Also include `show create table mysql.global_priv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Further investigation revealed that the issue described in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65554749/5025060), and my initial response to it (below) may be related to an *Incorrect definition of table mysql.event* problem.  In my case, I had 1) loaded a full dump (including the *mysql* database) from MySQL 5.7.33 to a fresh installation of MariaDB10.5.9; 2) discovered that [this was not a good idea](https://serverfault.com/a/1047492/406647); 3) edited my dump file to exclude the mysql database, and 4) repeated the load without deleting any databases or configurations.

This caused the database to function properly, but (in addition to the issue described in this Question) a) `/usr/sbin/mariadbd --verbose --help` would try to run the database server rather than print help, b) on startup the following error always occurred:

```
Apr 05 08:52:46 xxx mariadbd[22668]: 2021-04-05  8:52:46 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_B
Apr 05 08:52:46 xxx mariadbd[22668]: 2021-04-05  8:52:46 0 [ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler
```

Today, I was able to correct these problems (under Amazon Linux 2) by:

1. Uninstalling MariaDB-server and MariaDB-client
2. Removing /etc/my.*
3. Removing /var/lib/mysql
4. Reinstalling MariaDB-server and MariaDB-client
5. Reloading the database dump, again omitting the dump of the mysql database

At this point, I not only have clean database startup and proper operation of `/usr/sbin/mariadbd --verbose --help`, I also find that **`select * from mysql.user` works properly!**

So the problem of not being able to select from *mysql.user* appears not to have resulted from the change of *mysql.user* from table to view as I had originally thought, but from some other issue related to my "improper" database migration.

---

### My initial answer:

(included as a reference only)

After considerable research I have found at least part of the answer to this question:

**tl;dr: `select * from mysql.global_priv`**
then for each User,
**`show grants for 'XXX'@'localhost'`;**

Longer version, from [Authentication in MariaDB 10.4 — Understanding the Changes](https://mariadb.org/authentication-in-mariadb-10-4/):

> The password storage has changed. All user accounts, passwords, and global privileges are now stored in a mysql.global_priv table. What happened to the mysql.user table? It still exists and has exactly the same set of columns as before, but it’s now a view over mysql.global_priv...."

The aforementioned article provides not only what *what* but also the *why*.  I do not agree with all of it.  In particular the claim is made that *Old mysql.user table still exists, you can select from it as before*, but you cannot (hence this question).  Nonetheless I am relieved to discover a relatively coherent explanation from MariaDB.

Finally, here is an example:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.global_priv\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Host: localhost
User: mariadb.sys
Priv: {"access":0,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"","account_locked":true,"password_last_changed":0}
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Host: localhost
User: root
Priv: {"access": 1844674407370915, "plugin": "mysql_native_password", "authentication_string": "*9A87226E872127C756290C504DB5D9076E", "auth_or": [{}, {"plugin": "unix_socket"}], "password_last_changed": 1617303275}
*************************** 3. row ***************************
Host: localhost
User: mysql
Priv: {"access":1844674407371615,"plugin":"mysql_native_password","authentication_string":"invalid","auth_or":[{},{"plugin":"unix_socket"}]}
*************************** 4. row ***************************

MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'root'@'localhost'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
Grants for root@localhost: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING '*9A87226E872127C756290C5BF177504DB5D9076E' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT OPTION
*************************** 2. row ***************************
Grants for root@localhost: GRANT PROXY ON ''@'%' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Comment: This is perfect. That's what I ended up doing too, but didn't update the question here. It's amazing that people like you take the time to share this insight. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert missing privileges with this command:

```sql
INSERT INTO `tables_priv` (`Host`, `Db`, `User`, `Table_name`, `Grantor`, `Timestamp`, `Table_priv`, `Column_priv`) VALUES ('localhost','mysql','mariadb.sys','global_priv','root@localhost','0000-00-00 00:00:00','Select,Delete','');
```