# How can i reset mysql root password on linux manjaro

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When i try to use :

```
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
SELECT user, plugin FROM user;
UPDATE user SET plugin = "mysql_native_password" WHERE user = "root" ;
exit
service mysql restart`
```

it seems an error-->

```
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

Update and Alter is not working

Comment: Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o)

Answer (score 0):

It is a very bad practice to modify system data directly instead of using SQL commands.

The solution is to use `ALTER USER` command (see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/alter-user/) instead of trying to modify a system view.

In recent versions of MariaDB user data is stored in mysql.global_priv table, mysql.user is just a complex view which aggregates information from mysql.global_prov.