# Disable root login without password with MariaDB 10.5

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I'm trying to disable root login without password with the new version of MariaDB.

Usually, I set the auth plugin for root to "". But it's not working anymore

```
ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them
```

I tried to use **ALTER USER** but I've only succeed to set plugin to `unix_socket` or `mysql_native_password`

How can I resolve that ?

Thank's a lot.

Regards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o)

Comment: [root unix_socket auth isn't insecure](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security). It can also break you package upgrades.

Comment: i've see this issue, but nothing talks about set auth plugin

Comment: so is mysql_native_password safe ? because it allow me to login without password anyway

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by following steps:

Using command `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`

If you see a line similar to this one

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA
> mysql_native_password USING
> 'A_HASH_PASSWORD' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT
> OPTION

That means your root user can be authenticated by 2 methods password or unix_socket.

Now you can use command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_RAW_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Problem solved!

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! The problem is that if you select the "mysql" database and then run `SELECT * FROM user;` you only see "mysql_native_password" in the  "plugin" column and there's no mention of "unix_socket" anywhere, so it looks as if MariaDB is only using "mysql_native_password".

Answer (score -1):

If you look at `show create user` for `root` you'll see that both `mysql_native_password` and `unix_socket` exist as plugin types.

`unix_socket` will allow the root unix user login without a password. Insecure? Not really, they can manipulate and access database files already.

`mysql_native_password` is there, but the password there is invalid. No password exists that is usable so you cannot login with this plugin by default. This is there so that if you really want, you can set a password (using `SET PASSWORD`) to login to the root user from a non-root unix user. This inherently make it less secure  as there is another access mechanism.

Comment: Even after setting a new password with mysql_native_password, it always allows me to login without password (even if linux root and mariadb root passwords are differents)

I've installed the ed25519 plugin. Now it's working. I see this plugin is safe. Is it true ?

Comment: I've no idea what you have, or have done (a `show create user` was needed), what you want to achieve, why you consider root passwordless insecure under unix user with unix_socket (did you read [auth plugin unix_socket security](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-unix-socket/#security)?), whether this was the cases as non-unix root user, why the assumption that linux root and mariadb root passwords need to be the same (they don't), what is secure/safe for you. or how installing a plugin changed this all (and by implication changed a user). "safe" may have broken your upgrade path.

Comment: Indeed my definition of secure may not be the right one. I read that this plugin was problematic in the case of other users with sudoers access.

Comment: try asking the question again, with details.

Comment: all i wanted to say is some people at my university advised me not to use unix_socket nor mysql_native_password so i looked for another plugin