# cannot remote connect to MariaDB server

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

I know this was discussed and over discussed and it might be a simple thing for some of you, but being a n00b and trying to fix it by myself drives me crazy. I got two VPS's running Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS.

VPS #1 runs MariaDB server 10.3.34. There is NO firewall running (not iptables, not ufw, nothing);

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf looks like this:

    
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                    = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Doing netstat -ant | grep 3306 in terminal outputs:

```
netstat -ant | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:46154         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:59448         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:46174         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:46184         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:59432         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          127.0.0.1:59442         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:46162         127.0.0.1:3306          TIME_WAIT
```

I did add an user to MariaDB, grant all privileges with remote access and everything seems ok!

```
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE DATABASE xxxdb;
MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER  'xxxuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'xxxuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
MariaDB [(none)]> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
MariaDB [(none)]> EXIT;
```

VPS #2 runs Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS and also I got mariadb-client installed and telnet.

Trying: mariadb -u xxxuser -h SERVERIP -P 3306 -p

```
    mariadb -u xxxuser -h SERVERIP -P 3306 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'SERVERIP' (110 "Connection timed out")
```

Trying to telnet outputs:

```
telnet SERVERIP 3306
Trying SERVERIP...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Please give me any help / support that you can. Anything will be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You did: `CREATE USER  'xxxuser'@'localhost'`, but did you also do: `CREATE USER  'xxxuser'@'%'` ?   (Or you could use the ip-address of server2, and not use `%`)

Comment: Tried both... same thing!

Comment: Can you ping your server?  (using: `ping SERVERIP`) ? If not, then check the ip address of the server using `ip addr`, executed on the server).

Comment: `ping SERVERIP
PING SERVERIP (SERVERIP) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from SERVERIP (SERVERIP): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.854 ms
64 bytes from SERVERIP (SERVERIP): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.752 ms
`

Comment: It must be a firewall, if it's not on VPS#1, then it's still running on VPS#2.

Comment: It's a clean install of Ubuntu on both VPS's. None got a firewall installed!

Comment: If it's a fresh install, then: "Why Mariadb 10.3.34 ?"  (It's the oldest still supported version, see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-server-release-dates/ )

Comment: This is what Ubuntu installed under "sudo apt install mariadb-server". I didn't even noticed why!

Comment: The firewall could be by the VPS provider. `tcptraceroute SERVERIP 3306` ([traceroute](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/traceroute) package).

Comment: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` is NOT required to make [CREATE USER](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-user/) or [GRANT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/grant/) take effect.

Comment: `traceroute to SERVERIP (SERVERIP), 64 hops max
  1   23.XX.XXX.XX  11.131ms  12.758ms  1.250ms
  2   *  *  *
  3   *  *  *
  4   *  *  *
  5   *  *  *
  6   *  *  *
  7   *  *  *
  8   *  *  *
  9   *  *  *
 10   *  *  *
 11   *  *  *
 12   *  *  *
`

Answer (score 0):

If not able to login with root user

Execute the following steps:

1. Stop mariadb services

   2. Run mysqld safe version by below command: `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` &
   3. Run mysql client with below command on new terminal: `mysql -u root`
   4. Set password in user table of mysql database:

      `use mysql;`

      `update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("<new_password>") WHERE USER='root';`

      `flush privileges;`

      and exit
   5. Login with new password, set in above command:

      `mysql -u root -p Enter password: <new_password>`

Comment: Doesn't make any difference!

Comment: [Stop changing passwords like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540), its very broken, and wasn't the user's problem anyway.