# login error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: > YES)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I install on Ubuntu LAMP with MYSQL. I try login to mysql by command mysql but there is an

> Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
> YES)

. I try use

> Blockquote

`sudo mysql_secure_installation`

but it's the same error

Comment: So did you enter a password for `root` when you ran `mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: Show (without the password) the full command line you used with `sudo mysql_secure_installation`

Comment: First I enter on user account sudo mysql_secure_installation and I had line Securing the Mysql server deployed and next line enter password for user root, sow I enter root password and than I have Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: I don't understand it. How I should delete anonymous user if I can't login to MYSQL??

Answer (score 0):

Follow this step

- Change the password of root by mysql prompt

  mysql -u root -p

2. update password

   UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass') WHERE User='root';
3. Edited line in the file config.inc.php with the new root password:

   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MyNewPass'

Comment: 1 point I have Error 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Use [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) to set the password rather than ugly old hacks like `UPDATE mysql.user` as it has further consequences, isn't portable, and in the form in this answer, it isn't complete. Ref [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540),

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to access the database connection you need to give the password aswell. which you must have set during installation.

If you don't remember it you will have to reset the password.

Comment: I know password.

Comment: Try writing a code for access. Like using JConnector or something. If it doesn't work then something wrong with password or installation. Try reinstalling it.