# MariaDB can't connect as user with a password even though the password is set and the password provided is correct

Tags: mariadb, xampp

so recently, I installed XAMPP on a linux server. I created a user `user` on MariaDB, and set a password with PhpMyAdmin. Then, when I tried to login to the user, it gives Error 1045 (Access Denied). I know the password I entered was correct because I copy-pasted it into the input. I tried to login without a password and it worked! However, I need the password to work because I need to connect the database to PHP.

I tried `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='user' AND host='localhost'`, and I even deleted and recreated the user.

How do I fix this? Also, I'm using XAMPP 8.2.4. Please help, Thanks!

Comment: Don't update [mysql.user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o/64841540#64841540). What are you trying to achieve?  How did you create your user? What official documentation are you following to acheive these outcomes?