# MariaDB 10.11.6 - Trying to GRANT permissions to new user in HeidiSQL

Tags: mariadb

I'm on MariaDB 10.11.6, Windows Server Datacenter 2019 and trying to update user permissions but getting an error message "View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them." when I try and modify the User Rights through the data tab of the user table.

I did see something about that MariaDB has switched the mysql.user form a table to a view, which makes sense, but I can't find anything about to grant permissions.

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE ON `database`.* TO `user`@`localhost`; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Runs without errors, but also does not have any effect (both in the log and confirmed in the data).

How do I update the privileges now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o)

Comment: What do you mean the "GRANT" has no effect? Did you log in as `user@localhost` and perform a select operation on the `database`. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` aren't needed with `GRANT` or any user changing SQL command.

Comment: Hi @danblack I was logged in as root, and when I ran the GRANT query as I’ve indicated, the log indicated 0 rows were updated.  So I tried updating the data directly in the data tab.  I’ve read the GRANT documentation you provided in the other post but I don’t see what’s different between my query and the code from the docs.

Comment: new `grants` only apply to new connections. Did you reconnect? Is `select current_user()` show the same user that was given grant.

Comment: So I had a chance to try this and a) Restarted the service and b) rerun the query did the same thing.  Select current_user() gives me root@localhost; the user I’m trying to modify is backup@<hostname>.  Could that be the reason?  In previous versions of MariaDB - I am on 10.11.2 in Prod - this is not this difficult.