# Mysql c++ connector will not contact server. Same is true for mysql-workbench

Tags: c++, mariadb

I installed mysql c++ connector on PopOS (System76 derivative of Ubuntu) with the command:

```
sudo apt install libmysqlcppconn8-dev
```

It works.
I have a mariadb server running under docker but it turns out I wasn't hitting it.

I stopped docker (docker ps showing empty)

I stopped and started mariadb from systemctl and confirmed that is definitely what mysql is reaching.

So the system (localhost) is running:

```
systemctl start mariadb
```

I can verify when I log in:

```
select user();
select version();

and get root and 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
```

This is running on PopOS running a linux kernel 6.4.6-76060406-generic
if that matters.

I compile code, just showing the first few lines:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace sql;
int main() {
try {
  Driver* driver = get_driver_instance();
  if (driver == nullptr) throw "Could not get driver";

  // connect to hardcoded local mysql server
  // note: not good practice to embed password in code! just for first demo
  Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "sec3");
```

The code compiles and links

When run, it gives the error (same as when I try to run mysql workbench)

```
# ERR: SQLException in testconnect.cpp(main) on line 56
# ERR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (MySQL error code: 1698, SQLState: 28000 )

Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3060", "root", "sec3");
Connection* con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "me", "test");
```

I also tried running the executable as sudo (because I have to for mysql client).

[ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

I tried option 2.

```
sudo mysql -u root # I had to use "sudo" since it was a new installation

mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> CREATE USER 'me'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'me'@'localhost';
mysql> UPDATE user SET plugin='auth_socket' WHERE User='me';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> exit;
```

The update fails with the error message:

```
View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lacks rights to use them.
```

The plugin is mysql_native_password

Comment: I think the problem is with the configuration of mysql: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39281594/error-1698-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: @drescherjm acc is the database, not the password. That works on mysql. It asks me for the password interactively

Comment: I am sorry user error on my part (going by memory). If you don't put a space after the -p that means the password. With the space its a separate argument.

Comment: How did you start the database?  The `docker ps` output suggests you didn't include a `docker run -p` option to publish its ports out to the host (though the error message suggests you're successfully connecting to something).

Comment: Ok, I updated the question, because I mistakenly thought I was running against docker. I was running against mariadb in a service the whole time. But it still doesn't work

Comment: @drescherjm it worked. You should post option 2 as the answer. The update did not work, but when I went back to localhost, with user me, it works. With user root, it does not work. So the permissions did it. I think once when it failed, I had the wrong host name. But I am really confused, why does it not need sudo when mysql does?

Comment: In mariadb mysql.user is now a view that you cannot update. You should not really update tables in mysql system database anyway. Use create / alter user to set authentication plugin. Mariadb is not mysql, so you cannot take it granted that a mysql solution will work in mariadb.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ERROR 1356 (HY000): View 'mysql.user' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64841185/error-1356-hy000-view-mysql-user-references-invalid-tables-or-columns-o)

Comment: @Shadow, that isn't the answer to the original question, which drescherjm solved. Changing user permissions made it work.

Comment: This is the answer to the subsequent question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @drescherjm pointed out, option 2 was the solution. The view did not need to be set, that part is obsolete. But merely defining a new user and granting access was sufficient to get the code working. I should have just tried it.

Why root on the database does not have sufficient access is beyond me, but that's the way it is by default.

This problem taught me to first check assumptions by killing the server you think you are connecting to. There was another server running on localhost, and the docker had nothing to do with the problem! Having said that, clearly using docker and connecting to the docker name is a better way to organize projects for the future.